# Traefik - Load Balancing Port

Tags: docker, traefik

I have just started playing with Traefik and I have it setup in docker which is working well.

I route multiple containers through a vpn container...eg: net=container:vpn

I added the labels for each routed container into the vpn configuration and the rest of the containers work as intended, but 2 containers require the same port:

traefik.http.services.name1.loadbalancer.server.port=8080

traefik.http.services.name2.loadbalancer.server.port=8080

I don't expose the ports for each container, so I am unable to remap them, is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Could I see the docker compose file if there is one? I'm not sure I understand why remapping is not possible.

Comment: I use Portainer to create the containers so I don't have a compose file, I am still fairly new to traefik, but I add the containers with the traefik labels and use traefik as a reverse proxy, so I don't have to expose the ports, I just use the hostname...but when I route containers through a VPN container, I have to add the labels for all containers being routed through it to the VPN container itself, so they share the VPN containers local IP address, but use different ports, this worked fine until 2 services need to use the same port...does that make sense?